# Textarea and changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I have a textarea that I would send the changes to a database.
However I don't understand or find how to call javascript function when onchange is activated.
I've tried this first :

```
<div class= 'boiteContent'>
    <textarea id='id_textarea' onchange='update(this)' >" . [PHP code] . "</textarea>
</div>
...
function update(textarea){
    var name_field = $this.attr('id');
    var value_field = $(this).text();
    if (value_field.length >400){
        alert('La taille du champs ne doit pas excéder les 400 caractères');
        location.reload();
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Projectmanager/updatedashboard',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                namefield :name_field,
                fieldValue: value_field ,
                id_project : <?php echo $this->currentP->getId_project()?>
             },
        });
    }
}
```

I tried multiple ways , and the best, but still not working, is the following :

[My fiddle of the textarea Problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/Fayastone/ZGTjw/3/)

Could anyone help me having this javascript function executed when onchanges ?

I have to precise that I must pass in parameter the textarea objet to get the ID and the text() of it.

Thanks for your answers !

Faya.

Comment: Your fiddle != to your posted code.  Why is there an in-line `onchange` as well as a JQuery `.on(change)` ? if you remove the inline `onchange='updateDescription(this)'` and use the JQuery binding, fixing the typos, it works ; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/ZGTjw/4/

Comment: I  wanted to show you the two different ways I used after my research ^^.

Comment: In fact the value catched by the jQuery function is the old one, not the actualised, so the changes aren't uploaded, the database is uploaded but with the same value ( $(this).text()) as before :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be referring to the textarea name and value incorrectly. Change:

```
var name_field = $this.attr('id');
var value_field = $(this).text();
```

To:

```
var name_field = textarea.name;
var value_field = textarea.value;
```

I haven't the foggiest clue where the `$this` variable is coming from. Also, the `this` variable will refer to the `window` object.

Comment: Very nice idea, I have abandoned the jQuery solution presented on my fiddle and focused on the "onchange" property. Then, with your idea, it work. There, the correct code :

Answer (score 1):

This is what finally works. Thank you !

In html :

```
<textarea id='description_project' onchange="updateTextAreaProject(this)" >
```

In script :

```
var name_field = textarea.id;
var value_field = textarea.value;
```